# Can I use negation in collection filter using `python-arango`

Tags: arangodb

In driver [`arango-python`](https://github.com/Joowani/python-arango) a document collection instance have method [`find`](http://python-driver-for-arangodb.readthedocs.io/en/master/classes.html#arango.collections.EdgeCollection.find)  expecting dictionary as a filter.
But there is no much information on what is expected from the dictionary filter and its capabilities.
There is the only example that showing the match on equality i.e.: `{"foo": "bar", "boolean": true, "integer": 42}`.

Under the hood driver using `/_api/simple/by-example` REST endpoint and ArangoDB documentation do not cover this (or explanation is hidden from my abilities to find it.)

Can I use more complex filter dictionary for method `find` like equality negation or I must fall back to plain AQL queries?